# Bumblebee could not enable discrete graphic card after waking up from suspension

Tags: nvidia, suspend, bumblebee

My laptop is an HP Pavilion 15-n233sl with Nvidia GeForce GT 740M, running KDE Neon 5.9.2 with `4.10.0-9-generic` kernel.
I have installed `nvidia-375` driver from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`.

As suggested [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/08/how-to-install-and-configure-bumblebee.html), I installed and configured `bumblebee` from `ppa:bumblebee/testing`, and it works, as long as I don't suspend the PC.

After waking up from suspension, `optirun -vv glxgears` returns the following error:

```
[ 3598.915443] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 3598.915936] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[ 3598.916232] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[ 3598.916247] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[ 3598.916251] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 3598.916276] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[ 3598.916283] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-375:/usr/lib32/nvidia-375
[ 3598.916291] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[ 3598.916306] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[ 3598.916317] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[ 3598.916335] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[ 3598.916349] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
[ 3598.916438] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge virtualgl
[ 3598.916667] [INFO]Response: No - error: Could not enable discrete graphics card

[ 3598.916694] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not enable discrete graphics card

[ 3598.916835] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[ 3598.916882] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[ 3598.916899] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

and if I want to use the Nvidia GPU I must reboot.

I assume is not a problem of modules not being unloaded, since `lsmod | grep -i nvidia` returns nothing.

I tried [this solution](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=206828), but it didn't work for me. I also set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=force"`, with no luck.

So, in your opinion, what can the problem be? And how can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to skim through a power management section here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee#Power_management

Comment: In `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` I changed `PMMethod=bbswitch` for both `driver-nvidia` and `driver-nouveau` and rebooted, as suggested in the page you linked, but it didn't work.